# When an objective is accomplished, do we talk about it in the past tense?

Tags: tenses, past-tense, present-tense

I spent the past 6 months working on a software project. Now that it is finished, I am writing a report about it. The sentence below describes the purpose of my project:

"The **purpose** of this project **is** to allow its users to generate images programmatically."

I am confused about the correct tense for this sentence. Since the purpose has been fulfilled, should I say "The purpose of this project **was**..."?

I am also unsure about whether the word **purpose** is the most appropriate one. Consider this version:

"The **objective** of this project **is** to allow its users to generate images programmatically."

The same question applies in this case: since the objective has been accomplished, should I say "The objective of this project **was**...?"

Comment: *Was* the project the creation of the solution, or *is* the project the ongoing application of that solution?

Comment: @Davo good point.  I've actually assumed the latter in my answer, possibly incorrectly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd stick with the present tense: "The purpose of this project is to allow its users to generate images programmatically."

Even though you're not working on the project any more, it still exists, as **the thing that was produced**.  When you talk about its purpose, you're talking about what you **want it to do**, now that it's a real thing, now and going forwards.

If you use the past tense, then it implies that the purpose has **changed**, e.g.

> "The purpose of this project was to allow its users to generate images programmatically, but it ended up being most useful as a tool to ...."

or that it has failed to meet that aim, e.g.

> "The purpose of this project was to allow its users to generate images programmatically, but it failed to do this because ...."

I think that "objective" is a less "emotive" word than "purpose", and thus arguably better.  I think that "aim" is possibly better, because it creates a metaphor of the project as an arrow, aimed towards a specific target.  A project is a non-sentient, inanimate thing, and so one could argue that it's not possible for it to have a purpose or an objective - these are things that people have.  But, I might be splitting hairs here.  We do use the word purpose to refer to the intended usage of tools,  after all.

Comment: Were it me, I think, now that it is completed I would relegate the use of the word "project". Since it is no longer a project, why not say "The purpose of the new software (created from my recent project) ***is*** to turn men into women and vice-versa" - or whatever it is that it does?  The words in parentheses are optional.

Comment: WS2, possibly, yeah, but some people still talk about it as a project after it's been released.  Software is rarely finished: the release may be "V1" but development, and therefore the project, continues based on feedback from users, bug reports etc.

Answer (score 1):

"Now that it is finished," you would use the past tense:

> "The purpose of this project **was** to allow its users to generate images programmatically."

From what you've written, it appears that you **were** successful.